# Is there a way to install git into RedHat ubi 8 minimal images with microdnf and work around errors installing shadow-utils?

Tags: git, redhat-containers, ubi

Trying to install git into a Redhat UBI 8 minimal image with microdnf fails.  I've traced the problem I think to the install of shadow-utils, which git requires.  Trying to install shadow-utils alone fails as well.  I had no trouble installing other common build environment tooling until I added git to the list, and it started failing on shadow-utils.

I can work around by using a non-minimal image and installing with yum instead of microdnf.  Still, this seems like it should work.  Does anyone have a workaround other than using a larger image to start with?

```
~$ docker run --rm -it registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal /bin/bash
[root@965febf561a2 /]# microdnf install shadow-utils

(microdnf:10): librhsm-WARNING **: 06:29:14.389: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(microdnf:10): librhsm-WARNING **: 06:29:14.390: Found 0 entitlement certificates
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Package                                                                                                                                                                                                         Repository                                                                           Size
Installing:
 libsemanage-2.9-3.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   ubi-8-baseos                                                                     168.6 kB
 shadow-utils-2:4.6-11.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                               ubi-8-baseos                                                                       1.3 MB
Transaction Summary:
 Installing:        2 packages
 Reinstalling:      0 packages
 Upgrading:         0 packages
 Removing:          0 packages
 Downgrading:       0 packages
Downloading packages...
Running transaction test...
Installing: libsemanage;2.9-3.el8;x86_64;ubi-8-baseos
Installing: shadow-utils;2:4.6-11.el8;x86_64;ubi-8-baseos
error: Error -1 running transaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know for certain, but I believe that it is because your kernel is too old. I had exactly the same problem building an image on an Ubuntu 14.04 box with kernel 3.13.0-151 running Docker 18.06-1. The same Dockerfile builds fine on an Ubuntu 16.04 box with kernel 4.4.0-101 running the same build of Docker. I couldn't find any other configuration differences between those hosts.

Comment: That was it.  I had no problem installing shadow-utils in ubi8 minimal running on macOS Docker Desktop 3.1.0 on macOS Mojave, and no problem running on docker 19.03.08 hosted under Ubuntu 20.04.1 with kernel 5.4.0-65.  But it fails on Debian stretch 9.13 running kernel 4.9.0-8, running a Docker 19.0.12 release.  Thanks!